# How to add a header view to UIWebView with scrolling enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to add a header to `UIWebView`. And when zooming or shrinking the UIWebView, the frame of header will be not changed. It's like reading `view controller` of some email apps, example the reading view of Evernote.

I have found an solution https://github.com/protectedtrust/UIWebView-with-Header-and-Footer. But it is not perfect.It will layout the header view after the function `webViewDidFinishLoad:`.
But I need layout the header view before the function `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

so how can I that, or is there an solution already?